# Give Ubuntu Linux Mint's color scheme System-wide?

Tags: themes, mint

Is there an *easy* way to give (regular) Ubuntu the slick green / black color scheme used in Linux Mint's operating systems, whilst keeping all the "regular" Ubuntu stuff (GNOME, the Dock, etc...)?

*Surely* there is a Terminal command out there somewhere that could achieve this?

I don't want to change to Linux Mint though. I'm not a fan of the Microsoft-style user interface and I don't trust the security of Linux Mint, so I just want the color scheme System-wide, if possible.

Comment: If using the same desktop as the Linux Mint you like, the themes used by Mint can be used by Ubuntu in the same manner (ie. Cinnamon themes by Cinnamon, MATE themes by Ubuntu-MATE etc).  I believe all of Mint's creations are open source so can be used elsewhere (they're easily found anyway).

Comment: If not make it yourself ;-)  Look at the style sheet and match the coloring on a own made theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome has a very good tool that will help you create a custom theme of your own. It is much similar to how we edit CSS using " Inspect Element " in your browser. It is called `GTK Inspector`

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector

Once you enable it, you can click on any element whose colour you want to change and then replace it using the CSS window available in the `GTK Inspector` tool.

It will take some trial and error to learn. In the end, it is very simple to theme Ubuntu yourselves with a few clicks and some CSS. Good luck.

This is how it works

[image]

Comment: Whilst your post is in fact helpful, I was looking for something a little easier / with less mucking around... I just don't have the time to sit there and muck around making a new color scheme manually.